# rounding and converting value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some value with data type Numeric(28,10) (e.g. 128000,0000000000). I want to round it up to 2 significances and convert it into string. What is wrong with this?

```
convert(varchar,round(isnull(td2.Qty,0),2))
```

where td2.Qty is that value. It coverts it to string, but doesn't round it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does round, but it keeps displaying the zeros because this is how `numeric`s are always displayed.

If you need to stop displaying zeros, convert the value to a different type after the rounding, e.g. `float` or `numeric(28,2)`:

```
convert(varchar, cast(round(isnull(td2.Qty,0),2) as numeric(28,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(round(isnull(128000,0000000000),2)AS FLOAT)
SELECT CAST(round(isnull(128000,0000000000),2)AS NUMERIC(28,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the use of **ROUND()** function in SQL. It will not return the decimal value for the given length. E.g. **round(isnull(td2.Qty,0),2)** will not return friction value length **2**, but rather

> (e.g. 128000.0000000000) to (e.g. 128000.00)

instead of

> (e.g. 128000.12340000000) to (e.g. 128000.120000000000).

It returns only after decimal 2 value and remain all '0'. In your case you want ROUND to truncate. so you can use

> **Cast(round(isnull(td2.Qty,0),2)as decimal(18,2));**